# Identify if a column is repeated sequentially N times in a Matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I know that this question has been asked in a different way:

[MATLAB: Identify if a value is repeated sequentially N times in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494603/matlab-identify-if-a-value-is-repeated-sequentially-n-times-in-a-vector#)

I am wondering how I can exactly follow upper link if I am dealing with a matrix a coordinates, like: `M = [ x1 x2 x3 x4 ... xn; y1 y2 y3 y4 ... yn]`

for example n= 3 times:

```
M=  [ 2 3 3 3 1 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 8; 1 2 2 7 9 5 5 5 4 4 3 3 2]

ans: [ 4 4 4; 5 5 5] at position 6
```

I am looking for finding a column which has been repeated 3 times "sequentially".
In the mentioned link there is a way to do this for a vector.

Comment: Could you expand on your question a bit. Are you looking to do this for a known value or for any value?

Comment: Can there be multiple such columns

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
k = size(M,1);

%// fg is a matrix with sum of differences of n continuous columns\
fg = conv2(diff(M'),ones(k,n-1))';

%// coll is a row vector with column indices where fg is zero
[roww coll] = find(fg(k:size(fg,1)-k+1,n-1:end - n) == 0);

%// out_cell is a cell whose entries are the required matrices
out_ = arrayfun(@(x)(M(:,x:x+n-1)),coll,'UniformOutput',0);
```

out_ will be a cell containing `matrices with size k x n`  with columns which have occurred `n` times simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Translate each row of `M` into a unique numeric label:

```
[~, ~, m ] = unique(M.','rows');
```

Now you can work with vector `m` instead of matrix `M`, that is, apply to `m` the solution you have for vectors. The resulting index directly corresponds to rows of `M`.

Answer (score 0):

String based approach -

```
%// Input (slightly different than yours to properly test out the code
M=  [ 2 3 3 3 1 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 6 6; 1 2 2 7 9 5 5 5 4 4 3 3 3 3] 
N = 3; %// Number of repetitions

match = ['0' num2str(ones(1,N-1),'%1d') '0']; %// string match
ind = strfind(['0' num2str(all(diff(M,[],2)==0),'%1d') '0'],match) %// output
```

Output -

```
M =
     2     3     3     3     1     4     4     4     6     6     6     6     6     6
     1     2     2     7     9     5     5     5     4     4     3     3     3     3
ind =
     6
```